# Why is this line " while numA != numA[::-1]: " giving me "int object is not subscriptable" error?

Tags: python

So I tried the following variants without success either:

1)

```
numA = input("Type a number: ")
while str(numA) != str(numA[::-1]):
```

2)

```
numA = input("Type a number: ")
while int(numA) != int(numA[::-1]):
```

Comment: Because `numA` is an int and so isn't subscriptable.

Comment: The first line "numA = input("...")" should have already converted numA into str, isn't it?

Comment: you can use `numA[::-1]` when `numA` is a string.

Comment: numA is already a "string". Why are you asking me to convert into string which it already is????

Comment: `input()` gives string only if you use Python 3. If you get this error then you have to use `Python 2` - or you use Python 3 but you convert `numA` into `int()` inside `while`-loop but you did't show full code so everyone assumes you use Python 2.

Comment: Thanks, I think I saw the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast to string first, and then reverse. Move the parenthesis a little to the left.

```
while str(numA) != str(numA)[::-1]:
```

Since your version does not work, you must be using Python 2, which evaluates the value return from `input()`, which is an integer this time. If you were using Python 3, your code would've worked, as Python 3's `input()` returns a string, so you could've done it without casting at all:

```
while numA != numA[::-1]:
```

Or, in Python 2, you could switch to `raw_input`, which always returns a string, and not need to do any casting:

```
numA = raw_input("Type a number: ")
while numA) != numA[::-1]:
```

Comment: I am using python 3.5.2. But thanks! Don't know why the other two folks in the comment are asking me to convert numA into string.

Comment: @user7314729 - If you are using Python 3, either one of your code snippets would've worked fine.

Comment: It doesn't work with my python 3.5.2. If I do print(type(numA)) , i get "<class 'str'>".

Comment: @user7314729 - So, it's a string, and not an integer, so it should've worked. Perhaps you are running some other code than what you describe in your question.